# Can XEP online print a wide table without cutting it off?

Tags: jquery, html, pdf, css-to-pdf, xeponline

I am using XEP online to generate a PDF of my HTML pages. On one of them I have a wide table formatted to take the whole width of the screen. When printed, it cut the table side. I call it with this line:

```
<button href="#" th:text="another" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-sm active" onclick="console.log('t'); return xepOnline.Formatter.Format('all', { render: 'download' });"></button>
```

I already tried the formatter `{ pageWidth: '500mm', pageHeight: '500mm' }` on the script, but it don't seem to do anything.

Is there any way to print a wide table with this tool?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/dp32q89x/5/

Relevant code parts:

```
var click="return xepOnline.Formatter.Format('JSFiddle', {pageWidth:'500mm',render:'download'})";
```

This sets the page width to 500mm, with a table sized 100% with 15 columns.

One note: the formatter does not always get along with JSFiddle because of the Javascript that scrapes the DOM. It is JSFiddle issue, not necessarily the formatter itself but sometimes you get an error.

Result is:

[image]